# Change size of gold-email-input in polymer

Tags: css, polymer

I am trying to style the height of a `gold-email-input`. I tried setting the height with:

```
gold-email-input {
    background-color: var(--light-theme-base-color);
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    max-width: 670px;
    padding: 0px;

    --paper-input-container: {
        max-height: 48px;
    };
}
```

But what ever I try the `paper-input-container` stays `61px` while the `gold-email-input` resizes to 48px. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the height of the `paper-input-container` to match the height of `gold-email-input`, you would set its `height` to `100%`, and clear its `margin` and `padding`:

```
gold-email-input {
  --paper-input-container: {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

To style the `gold-email-input` outside of a custom element, make sure to use a `custom-style`:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="gold-email-input/gold-email-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <style is="custom-style">
    :root {
      --light-theme-base-color: rgba(0,112,0,0.4);
    }
    gold-email-input {
      background-color: var(--light-theme-base-color);
      width: 100%;
      height: 248px;
      max-width: 670px;
      padding: 0px;

      --paper-input-container: {
        outline: solid 3px red;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      };
    }
  </style>
  <gold-email-input></gold-email-input>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vKOJYm?editors=1000)</sup>

Within a custom element, you could use the style normally (i.e., without `custom-style`) inside the `dom-module`:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="gold-email-input/gold-email-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <style is="custom-style">
    :root {
      --light-theme-base-color: rgba(0,112,0,0.4);
    }
  </style>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      gold-email-input {
        background-color: var(--light-theme-base-color);
        width: 100%;
        height: 248px;
        max-width: 670px;
        padding: 0px;

        --paper-input-container: {
          outline: solid 3px red;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        };
      }
    </style>
    <template>
      <gold-email-input></gold-email-input>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo'
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OXVgKz/?editors=1000)</sup>

Comment: Very high quality answer! Thank you very much.